# Im trying to consume a WCF service with PHP but it does not return the result i want where do i go wrong

Tags: php, wcf, soap-client

PHP CODE is below

```
$soap = new SoapClient
("http://www.eservices.gov.bw/TolisExternalService/TolisPostService.svc
?singleWsdl",
array('soap_version' => 'SOAP_1_2',
     'location'=>'http://www.eservices.gov.bw/TolisExternalService/TolisPostService.svc'));

 $params = array(
    'licenceNo' => '2018/TEL/E/003'
    );   


$response= $soap->UpdateLevyPayment('$params');
$values = $response->GetAnnualFeeDueDetailsResult;;
var_dump($values);
```

WCF CODE

link for WCF service:http://www.eservices.gov.bw/TolisExternalService/TolisPostService.svc

Comment: What kind of responce do you want?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try with this:

```
<?php
// SOAP
$soap = new SoapClient(
    "http://www.eservices.gov.bw/TolisExternalService/TolisPostService.svc?singleWsdl",
    array(
        'soap_version' => 'SOAP_1_2',
        'location'=>'http://www.eservices.gov.bw/TolisExternalService/TolisPostService.svc')
    );


// List functions
echo 'Functions: '.'</br>';
$functions = $soap->__getFunctions();
foreach($functions as $item) {
    echo $item.'</br>';
}
echo '</br>';

// List types
echo 'Types: '.'</br>';
$types = $soap->__getTypes();
foreach($types as $item) {
    echo $item.'</br>';
}
echo '</br>';

// Consume SOAP
$params = array(
    'licenceNo' => '2018/TEL/E/003'
);   
$values = $soap->GetAnnualFeeDueDetails($params);
print_r($values);
?>
```

Notes: Tested with PHP 7.1

Comment: @KaboDire You are welcome. If you think that this or any other answer is best solution to your problem, you can accept it (just click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in)

Comment: How does one add a certificate to SoapClient request?